# Send chart with SQL Server without ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, charts, report, pie-chart

I'm trying to send an email through SQL Server using `sp_send_dbmail`. I wanted to add a pie chart to it, I tried using google charts, however my SQL Server doesn't allow access to the internet so it can't be done, also there is no SSRS installed on the server and I doubt I can install it (work server).

My table is quite simple.

My question: is there any way to send a chart on the email from a table to recap the results?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. You can add attachments with "sp_send_dbmail" but it isn't nearly sophisticated enough to send a pie chart. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the link to more information about "sp_send_dbmail."

I think your only viable option here is to have a document with the pie chart built ahead of time. If you want the chart to be built from table data it will require a standalone application in some language (.net, java, etc.) and from there you can save the file to a local directory. Use the "@file_attachments" property from "sp_send_dbmail" to get the attachment.